# How to open a picture pixels in a 2D matrix

Tags: ruby, pixel, image

What gem can I use to open a picture in a 2D matrix? I want to be able to read and modify each pixel individually.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/). Specifically you want the [`Image#pixel_color`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#pixel_color) method.

There is also an [`each_pixel`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#each_pixel) method to iterate through for reading.

Comment: Thanks for your help it does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

[ChunkyPNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/wiki) is also a pretty good library if you want to work with PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only for operations that will not be massive:
https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png

If you don't want to use imagemagick but need speed boost (ruby library with C inlines):
https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png